# Tag [upper-bounds] is nowhere to be found

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, MathOverflow has tag [lower-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lower-bounds) (100 questions), but **no** tag [upper-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-bounds). Are lower bounds that much harder to compute? Or that much more interesting?

Worse, due to the non-existence of tag [upper-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-bounds), there are questions on finding upper bounds with the tag [lower-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lower-bounds), e.g., [Good upper bound for a certain sum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/333261/91764).

Hence, I propose that tag [upper-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-bounds) be created **or** that tag [lower-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lower-bounds) be renamed — say, [upper-lower-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-lower-bounds), like on Mathematics SE, or simply [bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/bounds).

Comment: I took the liberty of creating the [tag:upper-bounds] tag, and of retagging the linked upper-bonds question.

Comment: A related discussion in MO editors' lounge: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/about-tag-for-upper-and-lower-bounds

Comment: I think the single tag "bounds" makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of creating the [upper-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-bounds) tag, and of retagging the linked upper-bonds question.

Comment: Note that [tags get automatically removed](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/create-tags) if they don't have a sufficient quorum of questions with the tag. Currently there are no questions with this one -- the example you retagged has been edited since.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is rather that [upper-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/upper-bounds) and [lower-bounds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lower-bounds) should both made synonyms of [inequalities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/inequalities).

I think that it's confusing and inconvenient to have several tags with roughly the same meaning and no sensible reason to be distinguished.