# `positive-characteristic` and `characteristic-p` are synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I thought that tag synonyms were meant simply to be proposed and left to survive or die on their own, but I see [another question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4912/should-tagfeynman-integral-be-a-synonym-of-tagpath-integral) in HNQ about tag synonyms, so maybe one is supposed to raise a corresponding Meta question.  I think that [positive-characteristic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/positive-characteristic) and [characteristic-p](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/characteristic-p) are synonyms.

EDIT:  As @MartinSleziak [points out](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4927/positive-characteristic-and-characteristic-p-are-synonyms#comment25243_4927), I perhaps stated this a bit vaguely.  Concretely, I already [proposed](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/characteristic-p/synonyms) the synonym, and it awaits the necessary votes.

Comment: I tried putting `[tag:positive-characteristic]` in the title, as in the [linked question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4912/should-tagfeynman-integral-be-a-synonym-of-tagpath-integral), but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the synonym ([tag:positive-characteristic]) $\to$ ([tag:characteristic-p]) was proposed and users with sufficient score in the tag [can vote for/against](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/characteristic-p/synonyms). According to SEDE, it was proposed in August 2020 by LSpice: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=positive-characteristic

Comment: As always, this synonym voting system is inept for such tags with not many ($\sim 100$) questions (I can't vote because it relies on the score on this very tag); it's likely the the number of authorized voters who will open this discussion be $\le 2$. So I guess the only door to make it a synonym is to make this question feature-request and rely on moderators.

Comment: I strongly approve synonyms in both directions, with a preference to keep positive-charactistic as "main" tag, the other being synonym — I don't like the symbol "p", implicitly meant to be positive, to be prime, etc, to be part of a tag; also positive in principle allows characteristic $p^2$, etc, beyond fields.

Comment: I agree with @YCor's [rationale](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4927/positive-characteristic-and-characteristic-p-are-synonyms#comment25249_4927) for which should be the main tag.  If I remember correctly, the reason it's this way is that I was forced to choose the tag with fewer questions (`positive-characteristic` currently has 83) as the synonym of the one with more (`characteristic-p` currently has 253).

Comment: Here is a link to a [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/about-creating-synonyms-by-voting) between me and @YCor concerning the advantages of bringing up possible tag synonyms on meta (as opposed to relying solely on voting). Of course, the tag management has one additional problem on MO - there aren't enough users interesting in discussing and managing tags.

Comment: The characteristic of a ring could also be a non-prime number, so I don't see how these tags are strictly synonymous (not knowing whether there are really questions about rings with characteristic 6).

Comment: @HenrikRüping, I think that was @‍YCor's [point](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4927/positive-characteristic-and-characteristic-p-are-synonyms#comment25249_4927) earlier.  I imagine, being mathematicians, we can find some shade of difference between any two tags, but, especially given their low traffic, I think it's safe to bet that the audiences for [tag:positive-characteristic] and [tag:characteristic-p] are almost, if not wholly, identical.